# Hibernate @Audited: NOT_AUDITED cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-mapping

I create hibernate entities over tables in database.

Entity A is referring entity B

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_A")
@NamedQuery(.. query="SELECT n FROM EntityA n")
public class EntityA {
....
@ManyToOne(...)
@JoinColumn(...)
private EntityB b;


@Entity
@Table(name ="TABLE_B")
@NamedQuery(.. query="SELECT n FROM EntityB n")
public class EntityB {
...
```

The only problem is that EntityA is marked with `@Audited` annotation (`org.hibernate.envers.Audited`), while EntityB is not.

When publishing the application, i get the following error in the stack trace:

> *Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An audited relation from EntityA to a not audited entity EntityB ! Such mapping is possible,
>   but has to be explicitly defined using @Audited(targetAuditMode =
>   NOT_AUDITED).*

If i add `@Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)` above `private EntityB b`, Eclipse gives me the following error

*NOT_AUDITED cannot be resolved to a variable*

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Have you included envers jars? dependency?

Comment: yes; otherwise eclipse would give me error at @Audited annotation, but this is not the case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If i add `@Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)` above `private EntityB b`, Eclipse gives me the following error
>
> NOT_AUDITED cannot be resolved to a variable

You are not using `targetAuditMode` properly:

```
@Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
```

Is wrong you should use `RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED` and not only `NOT_AUDITED` because [**RelationTargetAuditMode**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/RelationTargetAuditMode.html) is an ENUM  so to access its constants's values we use `RelationTargetAuditMode.CONSTANT_NAME`.

So it should be:

```
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
```

**Documentation:**

And we can see that from the [Hibernate Envers - Easy Entity Auditing **Configuration**](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html#configuration), where it indicates how to use the `targetAuditMode` property:

> If you want to audit a relation, where the target entity is not audited (that is the case for example with dictionary-like entities, which don't change and don't have to be audited), just annotate it with @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED). Then, when reading historic versions of your entity, the relation will always point to the "current" related entity